# Capture playback from website

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, video, video-capture

I have an ASP.NET tracking website that displays points on a Bing map as an item is in motion.  This website allows a user to playback the history of a particular item where the points will be plotted on the map.

I am looking for a way or tool that I can include into the site that will allow a user capture the playback when someone reruns a track.  I would like to be able to allow the user to click a button to "render" the playback and then be able to save it to their computer.  Everything I seem to be finding are tools for downloading videos from YouTube and such.

Comment: please tell us what is playback in your site? music,video,animation ? what kind of file format you are using? how playback are entered and offered?

Comment: Playback in the site is simply pulling information from a database and plotting the points on Bing maps.  There really isn't any file format associated with this.  The user is allowed to select an item and a date range and that's it.  Once the user selects the item there is a query made to the database to obtain all of the data points associated with that particular track.  I am trying to find a way to allow a user to capture the plotting of those points into a video format and save that video on their computer without having to purchase a third party tool themselves.

Comment: so in short you want to capture screen showing some map, and then make a video of all captured images?

Comment: Not really.  For example a map is displayed.  A point will be plotted on that map at the corner of 1st and 2nd street for example.  As the track moves more points will be plotted on the map and the map will recenter itself on the screen as the track moves.  I need to capture the plotting of the points and the locations on the map.  A better example might be the GPS in your car or on your phone.  Image taking the track you use to go from your house to a new location and turning that into a video and letting a user download it to their computer.

Comment: got it, but generally this kind of moving anchor on map is derived by GPS, how you gonna use asp.net application to do this? are you developing this for mobile platform? like mobile optimized website?